# Power of square matrices: decay rate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-norms

Given a real square matrix $A$ with its spectral radius $\rho(A)<1$, it seems well-known [[REF](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1023907)] that there exist $c \geq 1$ and $\rho_\star \in [\rho(A),1)$, such that
$$
\|A^k \|_2 \leq c \rho_\star^k,
$$
for any non-negative integer $k$, where $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the spectral norm.

I am wondering how can this be proved. Moreover, can we always choose $\rho_\star = \rho(A)$?

Comment: You should read about the spectral radius formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius

Comment: It is not necessarily possible to select $\rho_\star = \rho(A)$. For example, with the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1/2 & 1/2\\0 & 1/2},
$$
we find that 
$$
A^k = \frac 1{2^k}\pmatrix{1 & k\\0 & k} \implies \|A^k\|_2 \geq k (1/2)^{k}.
$$
there is no value of $c$ such that $k(1/2)^k \leq c(1/2)^k$ holds for all $k$.

However, we can take $\rho_\star = \rho(A)$ if $A$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

This statement (in the case that $\rho_\star > \rho(A)$ is a consequence of [Gelfand's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand%27s_formula), which states that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}\|A^k\|^{1/k} = \rho(A).
$$
By the definition of a limit, this implies that for any $\rho_\star \in (\rho(A),1)$, the sequence $x_k = \|A^k\|^{1/k}$ will satisfy $x_k < \rho_\star$ whenever $k > K$ for some sufficiently large $K \in \Bbb N$. Thus, for all such $k$, we have
$$
\|A^k\|^{1/k} \leq \rho_\star \implies \|A^k\|^{1/k} \leq \rho_\star^k.
$$
The constant $c$ allows us to extend this result to $k = 1,\dots,K$. In particular, it suffices to take
$$
c = \max\left\{\max_{k = 1,\dots,K} \frac{\|A^k\|^{1/k}}{\rho_\star^k}, 1\right\}.
$$
Note that we are taking a maximum of finitely many values, so this maximum is well defined.